# Any difference between these certificates from a security perspective?

Tags: tls, certificates

I understand some might buy a particular brand because, I guess, it's like buying a Rolex instead of a Swatch? But marketing considerations aside, is there any real security difference between the first ($36/yr) and second ($63/yr) certs offered on this page:

https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/wildcard/

The only difference I see between the two is they say the cheap one is good for personal websites and blogs, and the second is good for small/medium sized businesses. What am I missing here, if anything?

Comment: There's no real difference at all. Note the 'normal' prices are nearly identical, they're just offering a discount on the first one but not the second. This is like my weekly supermarket circular containing a promotional $x-off coupon for brand-X cornflakes but not brand-Y -- they're all cornflakes and probably actually made in the same plant but just filled into different boxes. BTW LetsEncrypt supports wildcard since last year and costs $0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All X.509 certificates used in TLS certify the same sets of data.  The security of the certificate is bounded by the key size and type (which you pick when you generate the private key) and the key size and type and signature algorithms used by the certificate authority to sign it.  Provided all of the keys and signature algorithms meet your desired security level and certify the domains and IP addresses you wish, there is no difference in them.

The relevant difference appears to be different levels of "assurance", whatever that means.  Since these are domain-validated certificates and the CA/Browser Forum specifies the approaches that may be used to securely validate a domain, there is no reason to believe that one of these is better than the other, except possibly for the pocketbooks of the sellers.

Do note that Let's Encrypt offers free 90-day wildcard certificates through automated issuance via the ACME protocol, and so unless you need a longer lifetime or a feature Let's Encrypt doesn't support (e.g., IP addresses or ECDSA roots), you can end up paying nothing at all by going with them.

Comment: 90 days? I'm a penny pincher for sure, but if I have to renew every 3 months I'll gladly pay a couple hundred bucks to not have to mess with it for 5 years. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Certificates are valid for at most 1 year.  You can pay for multiple years up front, but a new certificate needs to be issued each year.

Comment: Ok, but with LE I would have to install a new cert 4 times a year, right?

Comment: Yes, but typically you automate that process so you don't have to.  It just gets renewed, you restart the service at its normal time, and the new certificate gets picked up.  The entire idea behind short lifetime certificates is to limit the exposure of a compromised system and automate the process so a human doesn't need to be involved.

Comment: Ah, gotcha... will definitely look into that.  Didn't even know you could automate that entire process.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, certificates are same. It costs nothing to mint a certificate, what you actually pay for -- services and options. That is, support, maintenance and other things you can benefit from (for example, a discount for bulk purchase). Browser make zero difference between $15 and $150 certificate (except for EV, but it is a bit different and decaying story).